# How to Pass Different Types of an Object's Variables Individually to a Subview

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

Wanting to have a subview that can receive an @Bindable object's variable of different types. And, to simplify (reuse) the ClearButtonView in multiple parent views.

Is this a type of generic?

Given a model like this:

```
@Model
final class Servicing {
    var timestamp: Date = Date.now
    var cost: Double = 0.0
    var mileage: Int = 0    

    init(timestamp: Date = .now, cost: Double = 0.0, mileage: Int = 0)
        ....
    }
}
```

How to pass `cost` and `mileage` to a subview?

```
struct ClearButtonView: View {
    // what must this be?
    @Bindable var ???
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            .padding(.trailing, 10)
            .onTapGesture {
                // to modify the single value here for:
                service.cost = 0.0
                service.mileage = 0
            }
    }
}
```

To visualize the parent view:

[image: showing clear button in ZStack over TextField]

Comment: How about passing the entire `Servicing` and a `KeyPath` that leads to the property you want to clear out? Or, pass a closure that clears out the property you want and don't even both passing the `Servicing`.

Comment: @jnpdx Are you suggesting in the second option, to pass a generic closure? How to make it editable. Doesn't it need to be a binding?

Comment: No, closures don’t need to be a binding.

Comment: So this is not only for the Servicing class?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, only for the servicing class.

Answer (score 0):

jnpdx's first comment lead me to this ***easy*** solution.

The caller:

```
// for the cost variable
ClearButtonView(zeroValue: { _ in service.cost = 0.0 })
```

The modified ClearButtonView:

```
struct ClearButtonView: View {
    var zeroValue: (Any) -> Void = { _ in }
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            .padding(.trailing, 10)
            .onTapGesture(perform: zeroValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simplify to `var zeroValue: () -> Void = { }`

Comment: @jnpdx When I apply the suggested shortening, Xcode cries out: 'Contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, which cannot be implicitly ignored'

Comment: Interesting -- works on macOS, but maybe iOS has a different signature